# Get contents of form and then add on to url with php

Tags: php

I have found a stack overflow answer that shows me how to get the number of followers from Instagram. Basically, it adds the username onto the URL. I want to be able to get that username from an input box and then add it to the url.

```
    $raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME'); //replace with user
preg_match('/\"edge_followed_by\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$raw,$m);
print intval($m[1]);
```

Right now I'm thinking of replacing the username with `$_GET` and connecting that to my form. How do I pull off this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: in file.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
//check if length of username is greater 3 
if (strlen($username) < 3)
    echo "Kindly enter a valid username";
else{
    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/".$username;
    $raw =  file_get_contents($url, false, null, 0, 100);
}
}

?>
```

In Your HTML file

```
<form method="POST" action='file.php'>
<label for='username'>Enter Username</label>
<input type='text' required name='username' id='username' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have tried the code shown. It is not displaying the followers when I enter the name. However your "Kindly enter a valid username" thing is very nice. Have you tested it? I just can't get it to work. I got this error: `[08-Aug-2019 16:16:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents() expects parameter 2 to be boolean, array given in /home3/sixlloyd/public_html/jeffthecow/Projects/Followers/process.php on line 2`

Comment: Okay I'll try it.

Comment: It is still not printing the number of followers. It just shows a blank white screen. I am also getting the same error from before.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this code. I encode all the result via json from instagram. 
method:
1. Get username from html
2. perform a json decode on file get contents
3 output the result and try on your browser.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'.$username;
$jsonData = json_encode(file_get_contents($url));
echo $jsonData;
// you may extend your code from here to achieve what you wanted
}
```

Hope this code might help you.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I must not know what I'm doing because I am sure both answers to my question would work. This time the php did print out something `"\n\n \n \n \n\n` which is progress, but it is still not showing my followers. Any ideas? Thanks, I'll keep on trying.

Comment: Also, I know it is kind-of working because when I enter a valid username account it is `"\n\n \n \n \n\n` but non-existing accounts return `false`;

Comment: I looked at it again and it is putting a whole bunch of useful data for the webpage just into the title. :(

Comment: i am not sure how to print your followers. Probably someone could help you on this. For false username maybe you could implement if else block code. Thanks